# Different response from postman and Android API call

Tags: android, androidhttpclient

I am facing absurd situation in my application. I am requesting an API to get some data.When I hit through postman It gives proper data in int format like "0", But when I debug my code and get response from server its float like "0.0". Facing this behavior for an API. On browser version its working fine but on app side not.

Don't know whats going wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: post some codes also

Comment: I have the same problem too. Using Get API. Postman is showing updated results and Android App is showing older contents.

Comment: @unflagged.destination did you find any solution?